# Zend Framework - Zend_Loader_PluginLoader

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm just really starting with the Zend Framework, and currently I'm having a problem with the Zend_Loader_PluginLoader.

I managed to get a module specific plugin working easily enough using the following code:

```
class Api_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initPlugins()
    {
        $loader = new Zend_Loader_PluginLoader(array(
            'Api_Plugin' => 'application/modules/api/plugins',
        ));

        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->registerPlugin(new Api_Plugin_ErrorControllerSelectorPlugin());
    }
}
```

Edit: The class file is located at `application/modules/api/plugins/ErrorControllerSelectorPlugin.php`

I then tried to adapt this to get a plugin loaded for the whole application using:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAppAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'App',
            'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__),
        ));

        return $autoloader;
    }

    protected function _initPlugins()
    {
        $loader = new Zend_Loader_PluginLoader(array(
            'My_Plugin' => 'application/plugins',
        ));

        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->registerPlugin(new My_Plugin_ModuleConfigLoaderPlugin());
    }
}
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
Fatal error: Class 'My_Plugin_ModuleConfigLoaderPlugin' not found in /var/www/localhost/application/Bootstrap.php on line 22
```

Edit: The class file is located at `application/plugins/ModuleConfigLoaderPlugin.php`

So - since the files are where I would expect them to be as far as the prefix/path pairs sent to Zend_Loader_PluginLoader() and the code in both cases are the same, what's the difference?

How do I get it to recognise my application-level plugins?

Comment: And where `My_Plugin_ModuleConfigLoaderPlugin` locate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the app-level plugin to reside within the namespace `My_`, you either need to put the `My` folder out in the library folder or declare the app-level namespace to be `My_`.

Assuming that you already have other stuff within your top-level app that uses the `App_` namespace, then the easiest thing would be the former: move your `My` folder out into the `library`.

So, the plugin would reside in:

`library/My/Plugins/ModuleConfigLoaderPlugin.php`.

Then make sure that your `configs/application.ini` registers the `My_` namespace:

`autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"`

Then the app-level `Bootstrap` could contain something like:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAppAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'App',
            'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__),
        ));

        return $autoloader;
    }

    protected function _initPlugins()
    {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->registerPlugin(new My_Plugin_ModuleConfigLoaderPlugin());
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since your plugin does not sem to require any params, you could instantiate it via `configs/application.ini` using:

`resources.frontcontroller.plugins[] = "My_Plugin_ModuleConfigLoaderPlugin"`